# Managing ERC20 tokens with a multisignature address

Tags: erc-20, multisignature

Say I have the following:

- Address `A` belongs to me and holds 10 ERC20 tokens, but does not hold any ETH
- Address `B` belongs to somebody else and I need to send 10 ERC20 tokens there from address `A`
- Address `C` belongs to me and holds 1 ETH. Address `A` did not approve address `C` to spend any tokens on its behalf.

Is it possible to transfer these 10 ERC20 tokens from address `A` to address `B` by somehow using multiple signatures? What I was hoping for is to initiate a transaction from address `C` (since it holds ETH to pay for gas) or make address `C` initiate a transaction on behalf of address `A`. Or maybe there's a smarter way to transfer ERC20 tokens from an address that never held any ETH?

Thanks!

Comment: Is A a multisig wallet or a regular account?

Comment: address `A` may be anything. I'm just trying to figure out how token withdraws should work for a system where I have addresses that hold only tokens and addresses that hold only ETH

Answer (score 0):

If A is an external owned account and you want to transfer tokens then you have two options:

- Make tokens transfer: you need to pay for the transfer transaction.
- Approve a third party for the transfer: you need to pay for the approve transaction.

If A is a contract then it doesn't need to have a non zero balance, since the user executing the contract will be paying for the transaction.

Comment: Well, I was hoping I would be able to transfer tokens from `A` without ever sending any ETH to `A` and fund transactions from `C`. Address `B` spending any ETH to receive tokens isn't an option either...

Answer (score 0):

To add on to the other answers, the only way to send tokens from a wallet without spending any gas is if the token has gasless transfer functinoality, like [this](https://solidity-by-example.org/app/gasless-token-transfer/)